# Deep-linking Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, deep-linking

I need to add deep linking feature to my app with Xamarin iOS.
My `info.plist` looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>domine.somthing/index.html?UV</string>
  </array>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <string>com.domine.somthing/index.html?UV</string>  
</dict>
```

I seems not working due to "/" char in the URL.
How am I supposed to write `CFBundleURLTypes` and `CFBundleURLSchemes` URL values in order to make it work?

Answer (score 8):

Deep links can returns users directly to your application.
After adding URI support to your application like you did, just clicking on a URL consisting of a scheme name for your application will launch your app, but it seems you are filling `CFBundleURLSchemes` and `CFBundleURLTypeswith` with wrong values.

> `CFBundleURLName` - Usually, this corresponds to the bundle ID of your
>   application. Please see [Apple's Development doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) for more informations.
>
> `CFBundleURLSchemes` - Array of strings containing URL scheme names,
>   usually at least your application's name (without spaces). Pay
>   attentiont to ensure these values are unique to your application.

Look at this sample:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>com.yourcompany.yourapp</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>appname</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Now clicking on a URL consisting of `appname://` on the device will launch your app.

If you want to send a user to a specific part of your application, you need to add arguments to this URL, making a deep link. Here is a sample with a path and query:

```
appname://custompath?customquery=customvalue
```

When a user clicks a URL containing your scheme (`appname://`), your app's delegate is called and specifically the method `OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)`where you can handle schemas an execute correct app routing based on schema arguments (if provided).

Comment: I have only one link in the email and I have three apps like windows app and mobile site also a mobile app. How can I handle all app with one link, is it possible with deep linking or which is the approach for that. Which environment the email is open I need to navigate that application

Comment: I got a tricky solution for this issue with an HTML page. I created an HTML page and I can check the page is loading in mobile or desktop. if it is loading in mobile I can use the normal schema it will navigate to the app if it installed if the app is not installed it will show Safari can't  open the app and navigate to the mobile site. which can be done by javascript  '$(window).blur(function()'. anyone can do the next level according to their requirement. But I strongly suggest that try universal linking instead of deep linking

Comment: @Nerkyator Is adding CFBundleURLTypes all that is needed to make deep linking work? Doesn't work for me...